# Azure web app swap and user uploaded files

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, swap

I want to use the swap feature of azure web apps on my asp.net website.

Users can upload files to my site which are saved in a directory called `/files`. 
How can I avoid to swap these files and or any generated file by the application?

Btw: I can't see the files swapped when accessing the server via ftp?!

Answer (score 2):

By using a storage account directly instead of saving files to the OS disk.

**How to use Blob storage from .NET**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: every url has to be rewritten than? also whats about SEO and backups? There has to be EASY solutions.

Comment: You could map a custom domain to your blob storage (something like files.yourwebsite.com). It's a one time pain but would pay rewards in long term.